# Is there a way to use `ng-repeat-start/end` for the dom elements who are not sibling to each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs-ng-repeat

As explained in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) `ng-repeat-start/end` are cool enough to repeat some set of the dom-elements but I believe that we can apply the start and end tags only to the tags who are siblings to each other.

I have a different requirement like sampled as below:

```
<header class="tab-header">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(stayRange, rhPair) in rateHurdles track by stayRange">
            <a href="#{{stayRange}}">
                <span>{{rhPair.name}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div ng-repeat="(stayRange, rhPair) in rateHurdles track by stayRange" id="{{stayRange}}">
        <div>
            <rate-hurdles editable="true" scopeDataKey="{{stayRange}}"></rate-hurdles>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is can we club these two `ng-repeat` in two places with `ng-repeat-start/end`. Reason being I am sceptic of the fact that the key traversal in an object are not sequentially guaranteed in JS, And if so, I may get a mismatch of the tab-header and tab-content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use `multiElement` directives like that, you'll get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/uterdir?p0=ng-repeat-start&p1=ng-repeat-end)

However, this seems to just be an attempt at this other problem of sequencing. [orderObjectBy](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/) might help. Alternatively, just create an array of the keys with `$scope.rateHurdleNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames($scope.rateHurdles)`, and loop across that, using the key values to access onto `rateHurdles`.

```
    <li ng-repeat="key in rateHurdlesNames">
        <a href="#{{key}}">
            <span>{{rateHurdle[key].rhPair.name}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```